# Error with jtemplates with tables

Tags: jquery, jtemplate

I am using jtemplates with jquery and getting an error when I try to use tables in the template.

Following is working

```
<ul>
 {#foreach $T as record}
 <li>{$T.record.FirstName}</li>
 {#/for}
</ul>
```

but the following does not work and gives error **$T.record is undefined** in firebug

```
<table border="1">
{#foreach $T as record}
<tr>
 <td>{$T.record.FirstName}</td>
</tr>
{#/for}
</table>
```

Following is how I am calling template with some data

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [
                  { ID: 1, FirstName: 'Anne', Email: 'anne@domain.com' },
                  { ID: 2, FirstName: 'Amelie', Email: 'amelie@domain.com' },
                  { ID: 3, FirstName: 'Polly', Email: 'polly@domain.com' },
                  { ID: 4, FirstName: 'Alice', Email: 'alice@domain.com' },
                  { ID: 5, FirstName: 'Martha', Email: 'martha@domain.com' }
               ];

    $("#jTemplateDemo").setTemplate($("#templateHolder").html());
    $("#jTemplateDemo").processTemplate(data);
});
```

Any help in resolving this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at it, give this a try:

```
{#template MAIN}
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    {#foreach $T as record}
        {#include ROW root=$T.record}
    {#/for} 
</table>
{#/template MAIN}

{#template ROW}
    <tr>
        <td>{$T.FirstName}</td>
        <td>{$T.Email}</td>
    </tr>   
{#/template ROW}
```

If you are still having trouble I would recommend that you put the template in an external html file and use it like this:

```
$("#jTemplateDemo").setTemplateURL('JTemplates/yourTemplateHere.html');
$("#jTemplateDemo").processTemplate(data);
```

Comment: Thanks Randall. I am seeing the results correctly in IE 8 but not in Firefox and chrome. Any ideas why that might me.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Also are there any errors in Firefox and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The error was coming due to my placement of template itself. When I placed the template in a block like this

```
<script id="templateHolder" type="text/html">
    <!-- Template itself -->
</script>
```

templates rendered correctly.